# Adding an image to custom painted JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing

I tried to add an image to my `JPanel`.
First I dragged the image (.png) to the project folder.
Then I typed the following code, but no image appears, only black background.

### `GamePanel`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
    private ImageIcon i;

    public GamePanel(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension (1080, 720));    
        i = new ImageIcon("space-ship.png");
    }//end constructor

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent (g);
          i.paintIcon(this, g, 300, 300);
       }
}//end class
```

### `game`

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("space ship game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1080,720));
        frame.add(new GamePanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: "I dragged the image to the project folder" ... sounds like you are using an IDE.  Eclipse?  NetBeans?  IntelliJ?  Knowing which one might be useful.  The IDE may not run the application from the project root directory, but from a subfolder.  Or you may have dragged the image into the "src" folder, which is not where the application is run from.  The code looks like it would work (at least, until packaged for deployment), as long as the image is in the correct location.

Comment: first thanks for help ppl and im using eclipse

Comment: posted code is working - check if the image is in the project folder, is readable, is correctly spelled, and is really a PNG. Also check that the application is running in the project folder. If `i.getIconHeight()` is returning -1 the icon was not found/loaded

Comment: *"first thanks for help ppl"* Tip: Add @AJNeufeld (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. BTW - Did you try doing it the way I suggested? Some IDEs will automatically Jar a project when it is run. The approach using an URL will work with either a Jar or a loose resource, so long as the path is right. Loading the image by file path will only (***can*** only) work when the resource is **not** in a Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this in Eclipse - code works as is with "space-ship.png" located in **project** directory (not in **src** directory).

[image: Package Explorer]